# looking for a substitute for liquor in a cake recipe

Tags: baking

I'm making a Lady Baltimore cake the recipe called for chopped raisins and figs to be soaked in 1/2 cup of brandy can I substitute something other than liquor? This mixture goes into a frosting along with nuts and it is spread in the middle of the cake.

Comment: Sure, but the taste will change. So long as you are OK with the change in taste, go ahead...

Comment: What is your goal, the removal of alcohol or a substitute for Brandy?

Comment: For these seeking a general substitute for liquor in cake recipe (as opposed to substitute brandy in Lady Baltimore) - the usual approach is caramel syrup. Caramelize some sugar in saucepan (thoroughly, near burning), then dilute it with water until you have a syrup of thickness roughly halfway between molten sugar and water.

Answer (score 4):

If your objection is merely to using liquor then I would suggest [Brandy Extract](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004XVZMO6), technically, yes it does contain a wee bit of alcohol, like all good extracts, but it is inconsequential. (There are several good Brandy Extracts, the link is provide as an example, not an endorsement)

If you are simply 'out of brandy' and seeking a substitute, Whiskey or Bourbon would likely carry the closest flavor profile.

Comment: But one would scarcely soak raisins and figs in 1/2 cup of extract. Is there a suggestion for the amount of extract and what sort of liquid to use to make up the difference?